# Out of Memory Error while running this function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, papaparse

I'm using papaparse to convert csv file text to json,below function converts the uploaded csv file data into array of objects on button click, it works fine , but whenever we repeat this uploading csv file process , it shows out of memory error

This function invokes after we upload CSV File

```
checkCsvValidation = async (file, csvData) => {
    this.setState({ submitting: true });
    const text = await file.text();
    let result = parse(text, { header: true, skipEmptyLines: true });
    let errorIndexes = [];
    let emails = [];

    csvData.inValidData.map((item) => {
      errorIndexes.push(item.rowIndex - 2);
    });

    if (result.data.length < 2) {
      this.state.csvError.push({ message: "Please insert at least 2 records" });
      this.setState({ resetFlag: true });
    } 
      for (let i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        const checkContact = this.formatPhoneNumber(result.data[i].Contact);
        const checkEmail = this.isValidEmail(result.data[i].Email);
        emails.push(result.data[i].Email);

        if (
          checkContact == false ||
          errorIndexes.includes(i) ||
          checkEmail == false
        ) {
          if (checkContact == false) {
            this.state.csvError.push({
              message: `Contact number is invalid in the <strong>${
                i + 2
              } row / 4 Column<strong>`,
            });
            this.setState({ resetFlag: true });
          }
          if (checkEmail == false) {
            this.state.csvError.push({
              message: `Email is invalid in the <strong>${
                i + 2
              } row / 3 Column<strong>`,
            });
            this.setState({ resetFlag: true });
          }
          result.data[i].status = false;
          continue;
        }

        result.data[i].status = true;
        result.data[i].Contact = checkContact;
      }
    
    this.setState({ csvData: result.data, submitting: false, showTable: true });
  };
```

Above CSV Validation Function will be called after this changeHandlerFunction

```
changeHandlerForCsvUpload(event, fromBroswe) {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    CSVFileValidator(file, CSVConfig)
      .then((csvData) => {
        if (csvData.inValidData.length > 0) {
          this.checkCsvValidation(file, csvData);//checkCsvValidation Function
          this.setState({ csvError: csvData.inValidData });
        } else {
          this.checkCsvValidation(file, csvData);//checkCsvValidation function 
          this.setState({ csvError: [] });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  }
```

Comment: how & where you are calling it?

Comment: This function start by pulling a whole file into memory. How big are the files?

Comment: Hi  @SonuSindhu

  changeHandlerForCSVUpload(event, fromBroswe) {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    CSVFileValidator(file, CSVConfig)
      .then((csvData) => {
        if (csvData.inValidData.length > 0) {
          this.checkCsvValidation(file, csvData);
          this.setState({ csvError: csvData.inValidData });
        } else {
          this.checkCsvValidation(file, csvData);//checkcsvValidation function will be called if there is no error in csv File
          this.setState({ csvError: [] });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {});
  }

Comment: Hi@windowsill,File size is less than 1 mb

Comment: You aren't showing what `CSVFileValidator` is.

Comment: Also, never, ever mutate `this.state` like you're doing with `this.state.csvError.push`.

Comment: @AKX , CSVFileValidator is imported from library , import CSVFileValidator from "csv-file-validator"; which validates csv file records

Comment: @AsifMujawar Why do you use that library _and_ `papaparse`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247442/discussion-between-asif-mujawar-and-akx).